# Information is gotten from SNMP protocol difference info show on device

Tags: networking

I'm using zabbix to monitor network devices. My network device is switch 2960 Cisco. When I get information from SNMP using OID
ifAdminStatus.10005(.1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.7.10005) to check status Interface Fast Ethernet 0/5. I recived status **up(1)**.

But when i run command #show ip interface brief. Result is **Down**.Result as bellow

```
SW_QTM#show ip int brief
Interface              IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
Vlan1                  unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down
Vlan31                 10.46.31.251    YES NVRAM  up                    up
FastEthernet0/1        unassigned      YES unset  up                    up
FastEthernet0/2        unassigned      YES unset  up                    up
FastEthernet0/3        unassigned      YES unset  up                    up
FastEthernet0/4        unassigned      YES unset  up                    up
FastEthernet0/5        unassigned      YES unset  **down**                  down
FastEthernet0/6        unassigned      YES unset  down                  down
FastEthernet0/7        unassigned      YES unset  down                  down
FastEthernet0/8        unassigned      YES unset  up                    up
GigabitEthernet0/1     unassigned      YES unset  down                  down
```

Why does it have different value?
 Please explain it to me.

Answer (score 0):

ifOperStatus is what you want to query. Also, are you sure that index 10005 is the interface in question?